How to make sure my rust lib uses std or core but no alloc
I'm writing code that I want to compile for microcontrollers (that support the std lib or at least core) in the future. I want to use the std lib but not rely on alloc. I am avoiding things like String, Vec, etc, but it's hard to know which things use or not alloc.
Is there a way to mark lib.rs to never rely on alloc, just like you can mark ˋ#![no_std]ˋ to avoid the std lib?
PS: these could be mitigated via setting the target as the actual microcontroller, but rust-analyzer gets crazy when I do that and also it's hard to run tests, etc. I want a desktop solution

"I want to use the std lib but not rely on alloc" - I'm not sure this makes sense, in what scenario would std be available but alloc is a problem? If you want your code to work in a #![no_std] environment, then just use that.

As far as I'm aware, everything in std missing from core either uses allocation or requires an OS, which you don't have on a microcontroller. Did you find anything that's in neither of these two categories? If not, just use no_std.

You can use no_std (which disables dynamic memory allocation on the heap), but you could write your own e.g. Vec type, that uses static allocation. I.e. it would allocate a specific amount (size passed as a parameter to the constructor) of memory on the stack upfront. You can then add as may elements to this vector as you like, as long as you don't exceed its upfront reserved capacity.
